TV series similar to Hot Wheels World Race
There was one TV series with one of the best animations and the story goes like this:
'The main character studies in a school which teaches about racing. The Principal was the villain, one day the main character gets his father's car. This was the fastest car and I don't think his father wasn't alive. 
The last episode I remember was about a race which if you win then, you qualify for some other race and the brother of the main character died in that race, so that the main character can win. 
In one random episode his opponent, the principal's daughter, cheated by constantly changing the track (yes the race track can be changed if you have the authority to do so and the Principal also did this sort of stuff) he discovered that to ride your car upside down you need to run at a speed of 360 km/hr or miles/hr'
The race starts on a real track, then a portal occurs which kinda teleports you to the fictional track.

Use edit to update the changes rather then writing comments

It might be the American animated television series Speed Racer: The Next Generation (2008-2013) / IMDB

Premise / Wikipedia 

Prior to the events of the series, the original Speed
  Racer has disappeared to protect his family, but the main characters
  know that he is alive. Initially only one of the original characters,
  Spritle, has a major role in this show. Speed Racer is seen briefly at
  the end of The Note and more recently in Plot for Teacher, and he
  makes a full appearance in the pilot episode to Season 2. Another
  member of the original cast appears at the end of Season 1, Speed
  Sr.'s original mechanic and friend Sparky, who shows up as an adult
  posing as a Russian engineer named Chezko (he assumed a false identity
  to protect himself from Speed's enemies). In the three-part story The
  Secrets of the Engine, "Dr. Chezko" (Sparky) helps finally perfect the
  engine of the Mach 6, allowing it to run without gasoline. The rest of
  the original cast are so far unseen, and their whereabouts currently
  unknown.
Given the apparent age of Speed Sr., Spritle, and Sparky, it is likely
  that Mom and Pops Racer, as well as Spritle's living chimpanzee pet
  Chim-Chim, are likely deceased by the time of the series. Speed Sr.'s
  girlfriend Trixie is revealed as the mother of Speed Jr. and X, but
  she plays a radically different role, instead serving as one of the
  main antagonists of the series.
The series follows the adventures of an orphan teenager named Speed
  who dreams of being a famed car racer like the one he is named after.
  He takes a bus to the elite Racing Academy, founded by the Racer
  family, and soon experiences the difficulties of fitting in and
  competing with X, the best racer/student in the school, and Speed
  Racer's son. Spritle himself is now the headmaster. In the pilot
  movie, Speed discovers that he is the other son of Speed Racer,
  meaning that X is his brother.
Through the rest of the series, Speed and his new allies set out on a
  quest to get through the courses, discover the mystery of Speed
  Racer's disappearance, and try and build the Mach 6, a car that
  captures the spirit and gadgets of the Mach 5 for new generations, and
  the first car to contain a gasless engine. It is this Eco-friendly
  design that garners the attention of the oil tycoon Zile Zazic, who
  wants to destroy the car. It becomes apparent in Season 2 that the
  Mach 6 also possesses the power to travel through time, which becomes
  the primary focus for the remainder of the series as the series
  villains desire to use it for their own gains.
Another major plot device is the Virtual Track, a race track that
  transports racers to virtual racing environments known as the Virtual
  World. School faculty have the ability to add as many of their own
  obstacles as they wish, complying to school safety regulations.
  Whenever a racer is defeated in the track, they are automatically
  dispensed into the real world unharmed. However, like all programs,
  the virtual track can be infected with viruses or hacked, causing
  anyone trapped in the Virtual World to be affected.




speed racer the next generation opening

The animation quality is much better than this. Thanks for answering tho
